# return number and word regex javascript

Tags: javascript

can someone tell me why my code keeps returning null, it used to return a match now its not and i dont know whats wrong. I want it to find a match in the string for **1 hour**

```
var error = "null";

var str = "1 hour "


var strCheck = str.match(/[1]\s[hour]\s/g);

if(String(strCheck) != error) {
alert("works!");
}
```

Comment: Use regex `/1 hour /g`. The character class `[]` matches only one character within it. Don't need to use `String` on string, because it is already string.

Comment: you just need to use `/ yoursting /g`

Comment: Is the string `1 hour ` always or there'll be _10 hours_? If the string is fixed, use comparison operator(`===`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this..

```js
var error = "null";

var str = "1 hour "


var strCheck = str.match(/1 hour /g);

if(strCheck != error) {
alert("works!");
}
```

Explanation:

`[]` is used to match a single character  so `[hour]`  is not correct and if you have change in number of hours you can make it like this:

```js
var error = "null";

var str = "1 hour "


var strCheck = str.match(/[0-9][0-9] hour /g);

if(strCheck != error) {
alert("works!");
}
```

or Simply use `\d` to find a digit and `\d+` to find one or more digit.
For more see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) its simple and clear.

Comment: Also add some explanation, just code dumps are not helpful.

Comment: Not only explanation but a better way to check the match will be helpful to the OP.

Comment: I am not good in regex @tushar thanks to force me to read more about this and get more about knowledge about this.

Answer (score 2):

The RegEx `[1]\s[hour]\s` will not work. The character class without quantifiers `[]` is used to match only a single character from the characters within it. So, `[hour]` will match one of the character from `h`, `o`, `u` and `r`. However, you want to match `hour` as complete string.

To make the regex more dynamic and match even `10 hours` following regex can be used.

```
/\d+\s*hours?\s*/
```

**Code:**

```js
var error = "null";
var str = "1 hour "
var strCheck = str.match(/\d+\s*hours?\s*/g);
if (strCheck != null) {
  alert("works!");
}

console.log(strCheck);
```

If you just want to check if the string contain a pattern, use `RegExp#test` instead of `String#match`.

```
/\d+\s*hours?\s*/.test(str)
```

Comment: `\d` ==> `\d+` and `hour` ==> `hours?`, example _12 hours_.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of validation you need with that regex, but this can be useful:

```
\d+\s(hour(s)?)
```

Explanation:

- `\d+` One or more digits
- `\s`  A blank space
- `(hour(s)?)` a string *hour* with optional *s* at the end for plural.

The [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method returns an array with the results or `null` if no match was found. So I suggest you simply check the result as a boolean instead of compare to `"null"` string. Then you code could be like this:

```
var strCheck = str.match(/\d+\s(hour(s)?)/, g);

if (strCheck) {
    alert("works!");
}
```

Some [cases here](https://jsfiddle.net/n4ps9j85/).

Comment: You don't need capturing groups for `hour` and `s`. AND the comma in `match()`